# PHP Foreach Loop mail()

Tags: php, forms, email

My following script runs fine when a single email address is entered into the textarea, but once two are entered, no emails are sent. What am I doing wrong?

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Send Email') {

$email_addresses = explode(",\n", $_POST['email']);

foreach($email_addresses as $email_address){

$email_address = trim($email_address);

send_mail(  'noreply@noreply.com',
                        $email_address,
                        'Test Email',
                        "Hello This Email Is A Test");

}


}
```

var_dump($email_addresses) results in this

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(39) "email1@test.com email2@test.com" }
```

Comment: print output of $_POST['email'] and check is it separated by \n

Answer (score 6):

You're using the same variable name twice

```
foreach($email_addresses as $email_addresses)
```

so on the second loop, the source is overwritten

Edit:

please post the output of

```
var_dump($_POST['email']);
var_dump(explode(",\n", $_POST['email']));
```

Comment: Even when `foreach($email_addresses as $email_address){` I have the same problem.

Comment: fix the question to reflect this change. That way we know for sure you get it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
foreach($email_addresses as $email_address){

$email_address = trim($email_address);

send_mail(  'noreply@noreply.com',
                        $email_address,
                        'Test Email',
                        "Hello This Email Is A Test");

}
```

Also splitting using explode on `",\n"` separator isn't a good idea (people can send `",\r\n"` in some cases). Provide multiple fields or use `preg_split()`.

If it doesn't work try `var_dump($email_address);` after the `explode()` function to get the information what exactly happens with the input (and so you can see that input is actually correct).

UPDATE: As you can clearly see there is no \n in $email_address. It depends on your HTML form.

For a quick fix just `explode(', ', $email_addresses);` Also - you missed `,` in your input, which you require to explode that string.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried doing `foreach($email_addresses as $email_address){` and no emails get sent.

Comment: Could you update your question with the `var_dump()` result for misbehaving case?

Comment: I've updated the question with the var_dump() after the explode()

Answer (score 1):

obviously `a@b.com b@c.com` is not a valid email, and my psychic powers tell me that this is not the correct way to do this. What if I enter something else than an email address? Try to sanitise the data you receive from user. You can not trust user input blindly.

Comment: This is the just condensed version of what I have, I run other checks on the emails to prevent abuse.

Comment: Good for your code and the one who will be maintaining it. If I could design a webpage where user is just asked to click and select instead of entering I will still run sanitation check on server side.

Comment: This email script is for a referral program for only registered users, if someone is abusing it they need a verified account and logged in. It's not just something that the public will have access to.

Comment: Well, out of the context of your real problem, the first commandment of handling user input is, "Thy shalt never trust user input." even for registered users.

Comment: It's a little more locked down of a system than you think, but thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @jako, consider this use case. One of your user who can run this script somehow went rogue. He/she can compromise the system. On the other hand, if the user who runs this script is an IE user with lesser IQ, he/she would also bring down the system. And I am glad you are sanitising user input.

Comment: Ok, so I put a limit to X amount of emails in X amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($email_addresses as $email_addresses){
```

Means that you are overwriting the source array ($email_addresses) with the first entry in the array, because they are the same variable name. Unfortunately, PHP throw an error on this, so you end up rewriting your array with the first email address, and then prematurely (to your needs) exiting the loop (though this is expected and logical behaviour).